# Передача переменной по ссылке в js

Tags: javascript, ref

Существует ли в JS способ изменить переменную из функции передавая ее туда как аргумент, как это реализовывается модификатором ref в других языках?
Например:

```
var x = 3;
function change (obj){
obj = 50;
}
change(x); //x не изменится
```

А как изменить код выше чтоб x менялся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = { value: 3 };
function change(obj) {
  obj.value = 50;
}
change(x);
console.log(x);
```